# Vue dynamic mapGetters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a props that i want to use to make a dynamic mapGetters but the the mapGetters sees the props as undefined, probably because the computed is loaded before the props. Do anybody know how i can make it dynamic? my code is as follow:

```
export default {
    props: ['listType'],
    components: {
        addrow: AddRow
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            list: `${this.listType}/list`,
            current: 'Dropdown/current'
        }) 
    },
}
```

Comment: try it without `this` keyword like list: `${listType}/list

Comment: I tried that but then im getting an error: listType is not defined

Comment: did you try `list:this.listType+'/list'`

Comment: could you show how to call the component in the parent one?

Comment: Thanks for u reply, When i try list:this.listType+'/list' then its still undefined, When i console.log the listType on mounted it works fine, its undefined because the computed is loaded before props and everything, Im just curious if there is a vue function or something to archive this.

Comment: i usually call props in my computed property without any problem, so the problem is with ...mapGetters , i believe if you try `computed:{getList(){return this.listType}}` it should work

Comment: please please provide your store object

Comment: Thanks alot, i just tested the getList() that u provided and i see that that the prop is working on a computed so the namspace of the mapGetters is just not correct. i did some research and i found the solution, Thanks alot for your your help you really helped me i really appreciate it @boussadjrabrahim . I updated my post with the solution

Comment: welcome ,you could post the update as answer for future askers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[UPDATE]
I have found the solution thanks to @boussadjrabrahim
My working code look like this:

```
export default {
    props: ['listType'],
    components: {
        addrow: AddRow
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            current: 'Dropdown/current'
        }), 

        ...mapState({
            list (state, getters) {
                return getters[`${this.listType}/list`]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great for getters. Any thoughts on how to do it for actions?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `this.$store` for complete access to the store. So, `list` would become

```
export default {
    props: ['listType'],
    computed: {
        list() {
            return this.$store.getters[`${this.listType}/list`]
        }
    }
}
```

Use the dispatch method to trigger an action, like so

```
export default {
    props: ['listType'],
    methods: {
        sortList(order) {
            this.$store.dispatch(`${this.listType}/list`, order)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found that worked was essentially rolling your own `mapGetters` method in the `created()` stage of the lifecycle.

**Note that this solution has NOT been fully vetted and I have no idea what, if any "gotchas" it may create. As always, caveat emptor.**

```
export default {
  props: ['listType'],
  components: {
    addrow: AddRow
  },
  created() {
    // This can be configured a number of ways, but for brevity:
    const mappableGetters = {
      list: `${this.listType}/list`,
      current: 'Dropdown/current'
    }

    Object.entries(mappableGetters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // Dynamically defines a new getter on `this`
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, { get: () => { return this.$store.getters[value] } })
    })

    // Now you can use: `this.list` throughout the component
  },
  computed: {
    // Roll your own mapper above in `created()`
    // ...mapGetters({
    //   list: `${this.listType}/list`,
    //   current: 'Dropdown/current'
    // })
  }
}
```

Comment: how is this solution going to retain the same reactivity as computed props?