# Use props in computed and methods while mounting

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i am trying to use vuex/mapGetters and mapActions with props like so.
but the props are not defined while this code is executed. How can i achive this ?

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(`orders/${this.unitStatus}`, {
      getOrders: 'getOrders'
      ...
    }),
    ...OtherMethods...

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(`orders/${this.unitStatus}`, {
      isLoading: 'isLoading',
      orderUnits: 'orderUnits',
      ...
```

Comment: Can you add the getter or action code from the store?

Comment: How will this help ? The getters just return states and the actions run some gql code.

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was looking for.
[Vue dynamic mapGetters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577895/vue-dynamic-mapgetters)

```
export default {
    props: ['listType'],
    components: {
        addrow: AddRow
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            current: 'Dropdown/current'
        }), 

        ...mapState({
            list (state, getters) {
                return getters[`${this.listType}/list`]
            }
        })
    }
}
```